Looking for a Manhwa where MC is pulled into a game where he has to make a girl a queen
The main character beats a game and then was promptly reincarnated into the game as the male main character. He has to make the girl of the story a queen. Everytime he fails, he would gain a perk based on the ending of this life for the next lives. There are three stories where he reincarnates into. First, he is a hunter's son and has to make one of his village friend a queen, second he is a warrior and has to make his warrior friend a queen, and third, he is a begger, and has to make his sister a queen.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it colour or black-and-white?

I forgot, but I believe it was colored. I read it 3 months ago, and it wasn't finished. The main character also loops between the three stories I mentioned if he's already died more than 3 times.

Raising the Princess After Her Death


The long-term public service exam candidate, Minseo, finds himself trapped in the game, "Raising Lena" as he tries to escape his grim reality. In the game, Minseo becomes a character named Leo, and he must navigate through a world with three different scenarios to accomplish his mission of turning the protagonist, Lena, into a princess. However, the game "Raising Lena" boasts an overwhelming level of difficulty due to enemies who are set to thwart Minseo with their immense power and influence. Will Minseo be able to complete the game by making Lena a princess and return to reality?

